# Can a sportive competition convey a political message too?

Tags: united-states, policy, iran

[Reuter reports](http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/05/14/us-olympics-wrestling-un-idUSBRE94D0Z820130514):

> The United States, Iran and Russia may be at odds over issues including Syria's civil war and Tehran's nuclear ambitions, but on Tuesday their wrestling teams formed an unlikely coalition at the United Nations to keep their sport in the Olympics.

[Yahoo News reports](http://news.yahoo.com/iran-beats-us-grand-central-exhibition-220639359.html):

> Iran beats US in Grand Central exhibition: NEW YORK (AP) — Iran's wrestling team visited the United States for the first time in a decade and found a virtual home meet.
>
> The fans waving Iranian flags and stomping on the temporary bleachers were treated to a show of dominance by the wrestling power Wednesday in the exhibition at Grand Central Terminal. Iran beat the Americans 6-1.

[image: Iranians in New York]

I am wondering, after comparing the above two items from Reuters and Yahoo that how ironically it can be when you see these two different nations have same desires and ideas about each other countries against their own governments' desires and ideas and can show it in a friendly wrestling obviously far from of any propaganda and dirty politics!

Comment: You do not have a question there that I Can see.

Comment: That is a title not a question... By that i mean the question it asks does not meet SE standards for a Constructive question

Comment: Interesting read: [Where German Politics Falter, Soccer Succeeds](http://goal.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/05/16/where-german-politics-falter-soccer-succeeds/)

Comment: Please do not send the answer in comments. Comments are for improving the questions.

Comment: @PersianCat My previous comment is just a link, and link only answers are not acceptable on Stack Exchange. Even if it wasn't just a link, it doesn't _really_ answer your question (it's a relevant story, but not an answer). Also, while the primary purpose of comments is indeed to improve the question, using comments to add relevant but minor or transient information to a post is perfectly acceptable (check out the [comment everywhere](http://politics.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) privilege page).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically, Competitive sports have been used for diplomacy as a way of 2(perhaps hostile) nations exploring something that they might have in common.

Notable examples are

[Ping-Pong diplomacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_diplomacy) with China

the [Miracle on Ice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracle_on_Ice) hockey game with Russia.

But to use sports for more rigorous political discussion is kinda a stretch

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: I would classify your second example as a lot more of an example of using sports to rally nationalism and assist in a intranational level struggles than diplomacy.

Comment: How about the boycott of the Moscow olympics by the US followed by the Boycott of the LA olympics by the USSR...